# Msg 8152 with table variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored proc that makes use of a table variable:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE 
( 
    PartName NVARCHAR(150)
) 

INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT PartName FROM dbo.Part
WHERE ...
```

This proc sometimes fails with Msg 8152 - String or binary data would be truncated.

There was an inconsistency between the definition of the table variable vs. the definition of the dbo.Part table. The values in the dbo.Part table could be longer than the 150 characters defined for the table variable, so this would explain this error perfectly well:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Part
(
   ...
   PartName [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL
   ...
)
```

However: This error sometimes also occurred when the values inserted into the table variable were definitely shorter than the defined 150 characters.

The error did no longer occur after the proc cache was cleared, and was not reproducable after.

My hypothesis: Table variables can be cached. It could happen that the first time the table variable is created and populated, all values inserted into the PartName happened to be short. Since PartName is an NVARCHAR column, SQL Server might only reserve the space needed for the current values.

The next time the proc is run, the cached table variable is reused. If the inserted values happen exceed the reserved space of the cached version, error 8152 could be thrown.

Could this be the case? If not, what else could explain this behaviour?

Comment: If you know that there are values that are longer than 150 characters, why are you not defining the table [variable] with an appropriate length, or truncating the value *before* you insert them, so that no truncation error occurs?

Comment: @Larnu: I do now. This was a bug that is now fixed. I'm still curious about this (seemingly) odd beahviour though.

Comment: *"This error sometimes also occurred when the values inserted into the table variable were definitely shorter than the defined 150 characters."* Perhaps you are mistaken, and they are more than 150 characters.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the values were shorter than 150 characters in subsequent executions, yet the error kept showing up. Also, the error did not show anymore after the proc cache was cleared.

Comment: The fact that they are cached doesn't mean they won't be recreated when the type is recreated. Cannot reproduce your hypothesis https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa7e4d064b0588c93f11916f9dde15c4

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-performance/sql-server-temporary-object-caching
table variables can be cached, but only metadata is cached

Comment: Do you have any idea what else might cause this behavior (since you posted this as an answer)?

Comment: My only idea that during calls to your stored procedure you get different records from dbo.Part-table. In the first run all values are shorter than 150 characters and everything is fine. In the second call you get records that are longer than 150 characters and erros as the result.

Comment: What bugs me is that the error kept showing up, even when the inserted values were definitely shorter than 150 characters in subsequent executions.